# Takes exactly one argument (0 given)

Tags: python

```
class bmicalculator():
     #class created for the bmi calculator GUI and processing the numbers (pain in the ass to make)#
     def __init__(self,master):

          self.heightcm=DoubleVar()
          self.weightkg=DoubleVar()

          self.master=master
          self.master.geometry('250x200+100+200')
          self.master.title('BMI Calculator')

          self.label2=Label(self.master,text='Welcome to the BMI Calculator',fg='red').grid(row=0,column=0)
          self.label2=Label(self.master,text='Please enter your height in centimetres',fg='black').grid(row=3,column=0)
          self.label2=Label(self.master,text='Please enter your weight in kilograms',fg='black').grid(row=4,column=0)

          self.myheight=Entry(self.master,textvariable=self.heightcm).grid(row=3,column=1)
          self.myweight=Entry(self.master,textvariable=self.weightkg).grid(row=4,column=1)
          self.button4=Button(self.master,text="Calculate BMI",fg='red',command=self.bmicalculation).grid(row=7,column=0)
          self.button5=Button(self.master,text="Exit",fg='red',command=self.exit).grid(row=9,column=0)

     def bmicalculation(self):
          bmiheight=self.heightcm.get()
          print bmiheight
          bmiweight=self.weightkg.get()
          bmi= float((bmiweight)/((bmiheight / 100)**2))
          self.bmi = bmi
          print bmi
          self.label1=Label(self.master,text='Your BMI is %.2f' % bmi).grid(row=5,column=0)

          if bmi <= 18.5:
               self.label2=Label(self.master,text='This places you in the underweight group.',fg='blue').grid(row=6,column=0)
               totalindex = 'underweight'
               self.totalindex = totalindex
          elif bmi >18.5 and bmi <25:
               self.label3=Label(self.master,text='This places you in the healthy weight group.',fg='green').grid(row=6,column=0)
               totalindex = 'healthy'
               self.totalindex = totalindex
          elif bmi >= 25 and bmi < 30:
               self.label4=Label(self.master,text='This places you in the overweight group.',fg='orange').grid(row=6,column=0)
               totalindex = 'overweight'
               self.totalindex = totalindex
          elif bmi >=30:
               self.label5=Label(self.master,text='This places you in the obese group.',fg='red').grid(row=6,column=0)
               totalindex = 'obese'
               self.totalindex = totalindex

          if bmi >0 and bmi <999999999999999999999:
               self.button6=Button(self.master,text="Store Data",fg='red',command=self.dynamic_data_entry).grid(row=8,column=0)

     def dynamic_data_entry(self):
        #this is what adds the data to the database. Bmi has to be changed to the value of bmi and weightclass has to be change to the weightclass
          timestamp = str(datetime.datetime.now().date())
          bodymassindex = self.bmi
          weightclass = self.totalindex
          c.execute("INSERT INTO BMIStorage (timestamp, bodymassindex, weightclass) VALUES (?, ?, ?)",(timestamp, bodymassindex, weightclass))
          conn.commit()
          create_table()

     def create_table():
          c.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS BMIStorage(timestamp TEXT,bmi REAL,weightclass TEXT)')
```

Getting the error that `dynamic_data_entry` takes exactly one argument (0 given). I don't know how to fix or what went wrong. This is code for a BMI with a GUI, where i want to write the input from the user in to a database, along with the date. I'm having trouble writing the data from the input into the database.

** The function is a method of a class
*** Updated to add the whole class

Comment: Is your `fucntion` is method of a `class`?

Comment: Yeah the function is a method of a class

Comment: When are you calling this method?

Comment: Through a command when clicking on a button

Comment: @BenjaminInverno can you post the piece of code where you call this function?

Comment: add `self` `to create_table()` fucntion too -> `create_table(self)`

Comment: added self to both but getting the same error for both now

Answer (score 0):

I guess I have found your error.

You are passing the function that will serve as *command* to your `Button` class this way:

```
self.button6=Button(...., command=self.dynamic_data_entry).grid(row=8,column=0)
```

However, you are passing the method straight away, which will lead to the `Error` you're getting, once the method itself needs an implicit argument, which is `self`.

This `self` means the ***object*** of your class. But as you're passing the method **directly**, there is no object involved.

Therefore, you should do like this instead:

```
 obj = bmicalculator(master)
 self.button6=Button(...., command=obj.dynamic_data_entry).grid(row=8,column=0)
```

That way, you're telling the `Button` class to call the method from the object, and in this case, the `self` argument will exist because the instantiated object exists.

Make sure you understand the difference between `command=self.dynamic_data_entry` and `command=obj.dynamic_data_entry`